# Logging in, I get errors and a very strange prompt

Tags: bash, ssh, users, home-directory, hostname

Today I tried logging in to my Ubuntu system from SSH and I noticed that I have a very strange prompt:

```
I have no name!@(none):(unreachable)$
```

All tools such as `ls` fail with an error of `no such file or directory`.

Can anyone help me fix this please?

Comment: Seems like something is broken. Possibly hacked server, but impossible to tell from so few information.

Comment: Since the environment variables used to set up your prompt are set by `bash` (`/bin/grep -l "I have no name" /sbin/* /usr/sbin/* /bin/* /usr/bin/* 2>/dev/null` shows `/bin/bash`, `/bin/rbash`), your `bash` startup is broken. What has changed (on the target system) since it last worked?

Comment: @waltinator i logged in to the console and /etc and /home were moved to /usr, which was in /var for some reason. I moved them back and it worked. Someone must have gotten in. Rebuilding the server now.